# How to add data (rows) to a GtkListBox (C)

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I am developing a software using C programming language and the GUI library GTK+3.
I have made my window via Glade Builder and I made it so when I click on a button it refresh my GtkListBox.
I can access the GtkListBox easily, but the problem is that I don't know how to even add rows/data to my GtkListBox...

I have this function as a start:

```
void on_refresh_btn_activate(GtkMenuItem *refresh_btn, GtkListBox *list_box){
    printf("TODO\n");   
}
```

EDIT:
I have tried this code:

```
void on_refresh_btn_activate(GtkMenuItem *refresh_btn, GtkListBox *list_box){
    printf("TODO\n");
    GtkWidget *label1, *label2, *hbox, *row;

    row = gtk_list_box_row_new();
    hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    label1 = gtk_label_new("Hello");
    label2 = gtk_label_new("XD");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(row), hbox);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), label1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), label2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(list_box), row);
    //gtk_list_box_insert(list_box, row, 0);
    //gtk_list_box_prepend(list_box, row);

    printf("inserted\n");
}
```

I get no errors nor warnings but no results :'(

I would appreciate any one that could help. Thanks.

Comment: 1) don't post pictures of code. 2) are `gtk_list_box_prepend` and `gtk_list_box_insert` what you are looking for?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev
I have used tried to make a GtkListBoxRow and added a Box into it that contains two labels.. and than inserted via `gtk_list_box_insert(GTK_CONTAINER(list_box), row)` and with prepend too. Unfortunately it didn't work, I don't get any errors nor warning on the console and no results either.

Comment: Did you call `gtk_widget_show_all`?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Unfortuantely I did, I get the window and its elements with the listview shown  I have even added a row in the .glade file, it is correctly shown but I couldnt pack another row using code 

Comment: Did you call `gtk_widget_show_all` for the newly created row?

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexanderDmitriev 
You have been a great support, it worked just fine :)